# cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release: ERROR: EXCEPTION: TypeError: arg.slice is not a function

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, android-support-library

When I upgrade the cordova plugin `"cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release"` from version `3.0.0` to `4.0.0` I am getting the following error :

```
Cordova command 'build' started ...
cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release: ERROR: EXCEPTION: TypeError: arg.slice is not a function
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Android platform: V7+
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: No custom version found in package.json - using plugin default
cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release: ERROR: EXCEPTION: TypeError: arg.slice is not a function
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Android platform: V7+
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: No custom version found in package.json - using plugin default
```

followed by other error :

```
BUILD FAILED in 10s
35 actionable tasks: 35 executed
{ Error: /Users/.../android/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: /Users/..../android/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/engine/SystemCookieManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list:
  Error while merging dex archives: 
  Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
  Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/Users/.../android/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:466:23)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
  stderr:
   'Note: /..../CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/engine/SystemCookieManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.\nNote: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.\nNote: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.\nNote: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.\nNote: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.\nNote: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.\nD8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy\n\nFAILURE: Build failed with an exception.\n\n* What went wrong:\nExecution failed for task \':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug\'.\n> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list:\n  Error while merging dex archives: \n  Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.\n  Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy\n\n* Try:\nRun with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.\n\n* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org\n\nBUILD FAILED in 10s\n',
  stdout:
   '\n> Configure project :app\n+-----------------------------------------------------------------\n| cordova-android-support-gradle-release: 27.+\n+-----------------------------------------------------------------\nCould not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/debug, src/debug/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/debug, src/nullnullDebug]\nregisterResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)\nCould not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/release, src/release/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/release, src/nullnullRelease]\nregisterResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)\n\n> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE\n> Task :CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE\n> Task :CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE\n> Task :CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest\n> Task :CordovaLib:processDebugManifest\n> Task :app:preDebugBuild\n> Task :CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE\n> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE\n> Task :CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE\n> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript\n> Task :app:checkDebugManifest\n> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig\n> Task :app:prepareLintJar\n> Task :app:generateDebugSources\n> Task :CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript\n> Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig\n> Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues\n> Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugResources\n> Task :CordovaLib:packageDebugResources\n> Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugRFile\n> Task :CordovaLib:prepareLintJar\n> Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugSources\n> Task :CordovaLib:javaPreCompileDebug\n\n> Task :CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac\n\n> Task :CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE\n> Task :CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForDebug\n> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug\n> Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug\n> Task :app:generateDebugResValues\n> Task :app:generateDebugResources\n\n> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices\nParsing json file: /Users/../android/platforms/android/app/google-services.json\n\n> Task :app:mergeDebugResources\n> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests\n> Task :app:processDebugManifest\n> Task :app:processDebugResources\n\n> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac\n\n> Task :app:compileDebugNdk NO-SOURCE\n> Task :app:compileDebugSources\n> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders\n> Task :app:compileDebugShaders\n> Task :app:generateDebugAssets\n> Task :CordovaLib:mergeDebugShaders\n> Task :CordovaLib:compileDebugShaders\n> Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets\n> Task :CordovaLib:packageDebugAssets\n> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets\n> Task :app:validateSigningDebug\n> Task :app:signingConfigWriterDebug\n> Task :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug\n\n> Task :app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug FAILED\n35 actionable tasks: 35 executed\n',
  code: 1 }
```

My application contains many other cordova plugins and I can not figure out what cause this error. Can anyone help me?
Any idea is welcome.

Comment: I think I get from where the problem is : I have the cordova.plugin.diagnostic which depends of Android Support Library and other plugins that adds com.google.android.gms:play-services:+ which have a dependency with the support library...I think this is the problem which cause the error with duplicate classes. Still don't know how to fix it. I can not migrate to AndroidX because the plugin cordova.plugin.diagnostic depends og Android Support Library.